# Installing CakePHP with Composer

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, composer-php

I have installed and got working PHP Slim with Composer but I am have a number of problems with doing the same with CakePHP. I have, and do use CakePHP but with manual installs.

Now I am on Windows but I am using VirtualBox VM running Ubuntu Server 13.something.

So this is the JSON code I use to install Cake,

`{
    "name": "test-app",
    "require": {
        "cakephp/cakephp": ">=2.5.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "Vendor/"
    }
}`

Now when I run Composer, it install this all in my document root, '/var/www'. When I did this with PHP slim all I had to do was make a index.php file and require the 'autoload' file within the Vendor folder. But when I do the same for CakePHP, all I get is a white screen?

Now I have been following the guide at, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html -

But I am not sure if my index file is right or I should use a .htaccess file to point it to the webroot folder within the CakePHP folder? But the next step is about bake, which I just dont understand,

```
  Vendor/bin/cake bake project <path to project>
```

what does it mean 'path to project'? the path is /var/www? Or am I just not understanding something here?

Please help

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

**path to project** means the path to where your baked app skeleton will be placed. it can be relative to /var/www/ or anywhere in your filesystem. just be sure to edit ROOT, APP_DIR and CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH constants in the webroot/index.php

```
Vendor/bin/cake bake project myapp
```

*myapp* is now your APP_DIR

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using CakePHP 2, I suggest giving [FriendsOfCake/app-template](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/app-template) a whirl and poking around at how it is setup. I have used this for a handful of new projects recently and it works well.

In particular, check out how they [include the Composer autoload file](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/app-template/blob/master/app/Config/core.php#l30). Also, with or without the app-template, make sure that your web server is serving up the `/webroot` directory.